# Specific Reference for 't Hooft Anomaly Matching Condition

Tags: specific-reference, quantum-anomalies

Does anyone know, in exactly which paper did [G.'t Hooft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft) "*propose*" [anomaly matching condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_matching_condition)?

I scrambled across [his list of publications](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub.html), but I am unable to make out.

Comment: I hope this is on topic. ACuriousMind certainly [thinks so](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19359614#19359614), FWIW.

Comment: It seems to be G. ’t Hooft, in _Recent Developments in Gauge Theories,_ p. 135, G. ’t Hooft et al.
eds. (Plenum Press, New York, 1980).

Comment: @Qmechanic - Thanks, but a few queries - 1. You mean it wasn't proposed in any journal article and straight in that book? 2. Why do you use the phrase "_seems to be_"?   3. Is this source accessible somehow? (No preview on Google books). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short of any kind of validation, the above reference is what Google searches consistently point to.